# How to reload the game on Phaser 3?

Tags: phaser-framework

How to restart the game when you click on the button? 
I tried the following code:

```
this.scene.stop();
this.scene.start();
```

The scene reloads, but the preload function does not work again.

Comment: Why do you need the preload function to run again? The assets you loaded previously should still be accessible.

Comment: Could you share with us a code sample? Or your github repo so we can take a look into it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code:

```
this.registry.destroy(); // destroy registry
this.events.off();﻿ // disable all active events
this.scene.restart();﻿﻿﻿﻿ // restart current scene
```

Also have a look at the [Phaser 3 Documentation](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/scenemanager/) for more info